# Prime difference approximation given the product

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If I have the product $N$ of two large primes $p,q$ and I don't know them, is there any approximation(or lower, upper bound) of $p-q$ based on $N$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without more restrictions on $p,q$ you have $-\frac{N}{2} \le p-q \le \frac{N}{2}$

Comment: Smallest value $q$ can take is 2 so a very rough approximation would be: $p-q \leq p -2 \leq N/2$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Are there tighter bounds to this difference? Something like $N^{1/2} - N^{1/4}$. I just made that one up but I think you get the idea. ;), Thanks again

Comment: You have to define **large primes** in order to get better bounds.

Comment: If we had a good approximation for p-q, or p+q, we would have an efficient factoring method. I think it's harder to get an approximation for p-q than it is to get p+q.